# Spring boot MultipartFile methods

Tags: java, spring-boot

In Spring Boot, we use `MultipartFile` to send files from a client to a server. Here's an example of how to use it:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile uploadfile) {
    System.out.println("Name: " + uploadfile.getName());
    System.out.println("");
    return "Done";
}
```

I know that `MultipartFile` is an interface, which makes all of its members (i.e. `getName`) abstract. What I don't understand is, how am I supposed to use this interface without creating an implementation for it myself?

Comment: There is an instance of something which can be considered `MultipartFile`.  If there weren't an instance, it would be literally impossible for this code to work.

Comment: Can you give code example, i don't understand, in my point of view we use interface just to describe methods that can be implemented by other classes

Comment: And you get an implementation of that interface injected. Depending on which file upload mechanism you use. Spring uses a lot of interfaces to abstract you away from the actual implementation.

Comment: @Compass no it doesn't. file uploads are handled through a `MultipartFileResolver`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at Spring sources, you'll find [`CommonsMultipartFile`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartFile.java), which implements methods such as `getName()`

When you declare that you want to receive a `MultipartFile`, you don't actually care how it's implemented behind the scenes. You only care about the file. Spring Framework will decide which implementation to provide you with.

Other interesting implementation is [`MockMultipartFile`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/test/java/org/springframework/mock/web/test/MockMultipartFile.java), which may be used during tests. Again, since it implements the same interface, you don't need to change your methods in any way.

Since it's an interface, someone needed to provide the implementation. In this case, Spring provides it at runtime.

Comment: Thank for response, but how does it work, i mean forget about spring and just look at method String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile uploadfile) i get instance of interface that was overriden yet, but i don't know how  and which class override interface , how does it work?

Comment: You don't need to know the exact class that implements the interface to use that interface. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281203/how-does-an-interface-in-java-work

Comment: @АлмасАбдразак:  I get the feeling you should read up on [what an interface is](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) before continuing much further with Spring.  Large amounts of Spring are built on the principles supplied with interfaces.

Comment: Thank you , probably i don't understand how interfaces really work, i know that it should be new question, but can you give me some code example of how we can path a reference to interface that is overriden by another class?

Comment: @АлмасАбдразак With IntelliJ, Ctrl+Alt+B is Find Implementation(s) which is a good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

How Spring MVC handles file uploads is explained in the [relevant section](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-multipart) of the Spring Reference Guide.

When a request comes in it first reaches the `DispatcherServlet`, it will detect that it is a multipart request and with that delegate the request processing to a configured [`MultipartResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartResolver.html) (which is again an interface). The `DispatcherServlet` detects this `MultipartResolver` by a well known name `multipartResolver` (this is hardcoded in the `DispatcherServlet`).

What this `MultipartResolver` instances do is wrap the actual `HttpServletRequest` into a `MultipartServletRequest` (which is a Spring MVC extension to the `HttpServletRequest) and this wrapper knowns how to handle the incoming request and create the appropriate`MultipartFile` implementations.

Spring has 3 flavors of this interface

1. `CommonsMultipartResolver` using [Apache Commons FileUpload](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/)
2. `StandardServletMultipartResolver` using the Servlet 3.0 standard Servlet API file upload
3. `MockMultipartFile` for unit testing

When using Spring Boot to [handle file uploads](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-multipart-file-upload-configuration) it [configures](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/MultipartAutoConfiguration.java#L72) by default the second option the `StandardServletMultipartResolver`.

Now when the complex processing of the multipart request is done, the `DispatcherServlet` passes on the request to the selected handler (i.e. your controller). The `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` inspects the selected request handling method and will fill in all method arguments.

In the end it is the `RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver` which binds an actual value to the `MultipartFile` object. Using the `getFiles` method on the `MultipartServletRequest`. For the default Spring Boot configured implementation (the [`StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/support/StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.html)) this will give instances of [`StandardMultipartFile`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/multipart/support/StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java#L263) which is an embedded class in said `StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest`

The advantage of being able to use the `MultipartFile` interface is that you could change to `CommonsMultipartResolver` without having to change your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Spring has some class implementing `MultipartFile` interface. For example, there is `CommonsMultipartFile` class: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartFile.html

When a multipart form is submitted to your controller, Spring parses the form, builds some object of class implementing `MultipartFile` (probably that `CommonsMultipartFile`) and calls your controller method with this object as a parameter.

So you don't need to implement `MultipartFile` methods, they are already implemented by Spring.

Answer (score 0):

```
var factory = new DiskFileItemFactory()
var fileItem = factory.createItem(
        "file",
        MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE,
        true,
        "file"
)

try {
    fileItem.outputStream.use { outputStream ->
        // Copy your data into the outputStream
    }

    var multipartFile = new CommonsMultipartFile(fileItem)
} finally {
    fileItem.delete()
}
```